# Epipremnum Aureum clone has brown roots

Tags: vines, propagation, roots

A clone that i had placed in water nearly a month ago has fairly long roots. However, they are starting to turn brown on the tips. Any idea what is happening? This clone took a long time to  root, around three weeks. The roots have been growing for about a week now. A second clone that i placed in a different bottle of water with fertilizer rooted quicker, about a week, however its roots are starting to darken too. Should i plant the second one asap? And is the first one saveable at all?

**First Plant:**

[image]

[image]

**Second Plant**

[image]

[image]
They are both kept in a window where light is available. Should i shield the roots from light?

I added miracle grow liquid fertilizer to substitute for soil in both of these solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fertilizer is not normally required or recommended to get pothos or [epipremnum aureum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epipremnum_aureum) to root. This is tough tropical vine that has become naturalized around the world but makes a great house plant. If the ends of the roots are soft and mushy then trim them back and replace the water.  If the root tips are firm then don't worry about the colour.

You can trim the roots with a straight edge razor blade to encourage branching and more root mass.

With the amount of roots you have you could pot these cuttings up right now as long as they were in good light.

Answer (score 1):

Never add fertilizer.  The cuttings of any plant spawn roots to search for food (Nitrogen, the nutrient that makes the leaves green).